# How to do HTTP-Only Cookie based authentication using flutter and graphql api

Tags: dart, graphql, flutter-graphql

I am currently using `graphql_flutter: ^5.1.2` for fetching Graphql api. On the host server there is used httponly cookie based authentication. In react there is http only option for cookie but on graphql_flutter i can't find any option like that . I already test this system using dio client . But it doesn't work for me.

Please anyone give me a solution how can I solve this problem .

```
 final dio = Dio();
  final cookieJar = CookieJar(); //PersistCookieJar(); //todo.
  dio.interceptors.add(CookieManager(cookieJar));

  final Link _dioLink = DioLink(
    graphqlEndpoint,
    client: dio,
  );
```

solve http-only cookie based authentication system using flutter graphql.